# How to add delay in foreach

Tags: angular7

Please let me know how to add "delay" for "setTimeout" in angular 6 with forEach loop
to execute each loop after specific interval.

Below is my code.

```
selectedPlans.forEach(async (selectedPlan) => {
 this.makePayment(selectedPlan) 
});
```

In above code "makePayment" needs to be call after specific interval.

Thanks